# Dimension of Hamiltonian & Diagonalizability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations, ising-model

Often in condensed matter physics literature, one encounters a Hamiltonian that goes something like :
$$
H = \sum_{i=1}^{n} J_{i}\ S_{i}^{z} S_{i+1}^{z},
$$
where $J_{i}$ are the coupling constants, $S_{i}^{z}$ representing the spin operator $S^{z}$ acting at $i^{\text{th}}$ site and $n$ being the total number of sites (with perhaps a ring-like identification). Now, $S^{z}$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with the spin at any particular site being a $2 \times 1$ matrix or column vector.

If one knew the wavefunction like $|\psi \rangle = \dots \otimes | i \rangle \otimes | i+1 \rangle \otimes \cdots $, then it would be easy to simply apply the Hamiltonian and do whatever one wants. But suppose that I don't have that $| \psi \rangle$ and need to directly diagonalize $H$ to calculate its eigenvalues & eigenvectors (for e.g., while simulating such a model on a lattice on computer), how would I go about doing that?

How would one make sure that $S^{z}_{i}$ is different from $S^{z}_{i+1}$? The only way to do that is to operate them on some presumed (random) spin existing at their sites. But if one does that then the Hamiltonian is a summation of product of two $2 \times 1$ matrices ($[2 \times 2]\ *\ [2 \times 1] \to [2 \times 1]$ matrix) which doesn't make sense!

Could someone elaborate where I'm going wrong? Basically, I want to diagonalize a Hamiltonian of the form above on a computer (using, say, Mathematica - which has inbuilt functions to give the eigenvalues & eigenvectors) without knowing the eigenfunctions.

Edit :
Upon further thought, by saying that the spin at any particular site is a $2 \times 1$ matrix, am I implicitly assuming that it is a non-tensor state? Even if that's true, how does it help give the correct dimension of the Hamiltonian to diagonalize it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Dimension of the Hilbert space

The Hilbert space of a spin chain of length $n$ is given by the tensor product of $n$ copies of the Hilbert space of a single spin. Assuming we are talking about spin-$\frac{1}{2}$, the dimension of the space is $2^n$.

In this context, an "operator acting on a single spin" means a $2^n$-dimensional operator obtained as the tensor product of a 2d operator with $n-1$ copies of the 2d identity, so that the action on the other spins is trivial.

For example, given the ($2\times2$) Pauli matrix $\sigma^z$,

$$ S_i^z = \underbrace{\mathbb{I}_2 \otimes \cdots\otimes \mathbb{I}_2}_{i-1}\otimes \sigma^z\otimes\underbrace{\mathbb{I}_2\otimes \cdots\otimes \mathbb{I}_2}_{n-i} . $$

Similarly, a "two-body" operator $S_i^z S_{i+1}^z$ can be explicitly written

$$ S_i^z S_{i+1}^z = \underbrace{\mathbb{I}_2 \otimes \cdots\otimes \mathbb{I}_2}_{i-1}\otimes \sigma^z\otimes \sigma^z\otimes\underbrace{\mathbb{I}_2\otimes \cdots\otimes \mathbb{I}_2}_{n-i-1}, $$
and so on.

#### Numerical diagonalisation

Diagonalising such a Hamiltonian numerically is a hard problem. In principle, with the expressions above you can construct explicitly the matrix in your favourite programming language (e.g. in Mathematica using `KroneckerProduct` and `PauliMatrix`). However, as noted above, the dimension grows exponentially with the number of spins, meaning you will not be able even get to $n\approx 20$.

Therefore one needs to find smarter ways to do things; for example a starting point would be to represent $H$ as a sparse matrix. This is an active field of research, and even with state of the art algorithms and big computers, people are able to solve the problem with at most a few tens spins.